# Server that receives a sequence of integers

Tags: java, sockets, stream, serversocket

I'm learning Sockets programming in Java. I'm trying to solve a problem that consists in:

1. Having a server that accepts a connection from one client on a
   time. That part is solved.
2. Now I want the server to receive a sequence of integers in text
   format that will finish when a end of file situation on the socket
   reader stream is detected.
3. I'm trying to do this using DataInputStream and
   DataOutputStream because thats the only thing that I know so far.

Can somebody help? I don't know how to the 2nd part of my problem.

I have the following code:

```
  public class Exercise{

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        ServerSocket server= new ServerSocket(6789);
        while(true) {
            try {
                Socket aux= server.accept();
                DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(aux.getInputStream());
                DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(aux.getOutputStream());
                while(dis != null) {
                }
            }
            catch (EOFException e) {
                out.println("The client finish execution!");
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Um, why the outer while (true) loop? And dis will certainly *never* be null. Furthermore, you must specify a way that the integers are separated from each other. To read strings, use a reader such as BufferedReader instead of a DataStream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to *define a protocol of data exchange*. That's how all of the networking applications work. The client and server have to agree on a FORMAT and SEQUENCE of data that will be exchanged. The most basic thing you can do is send the following in sequence

START

1,2,3,4,5,6

STOP

The moment you receive START, you know the next input line is your sequence of integers which you can parse using your custom logic.

Once you receive STOP you know there wont be any more data and you stop and return the response/acknowledgement to the client.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this page from the oracle website http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/socket-140484.html#server should have all the info you need to setup and receive String data from a socket connection.

To process a sequence of integers, would depend on the formatting, so you would want to make sure that they are seperated by space or some standard delimiter like white-space or comma (i.e. "1 2 3 4" or "1,2,3,4") and then use the StringTokenizer or a similar class to break up the String into individual integer Strings and then parse with Integer.parseInt();